# Regarding the tab size in vim

Tags: linux, vim

I have already setup vim size to 4 in ~/.vimrc. It is working when I enter tab, but the original file display tab in size 8. How to make them all in size 4?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:verbose setlocal tabstop? softtabstop? expandtab? shiftwidth?
```

will show you the current indent settings (and where it got defined). Since these are *buffer-local* settings, it's not enough to set this once in your `~/.vimrc`. Several *filetype plugins* change these indent settings. (Though typically not `'tabstop'`, but rather `'softtabstop'`.

You could avoid that by turning off filetype plugins altogether (drop `:filetype plugin on` from your `~/.vimrc`), but it's better to selectively override this in the *after* directory.

Put your `:setlocal ...` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.) Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType {filetype\} ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.